# How to open a new dialog box in lwc in a pop up window instead opening in a tab or subtab

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

How to open a new dialog box in lwc in a pop up window instead opening in a tab or subtab. I tried opening using navigation.maxin but it opens in a subtab

I have a lwc component  and used a lightning button

```js
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__objectPage',
                attributes: {
                    objectApiName: 'Account',
                    actionName: 'new'
                }
            });

:html code
 <lightning-button
            variant="brand"
            label="Click to create record"
            onclick={newRecord}
            class="slds-m-around_large"
            >
            </lightning-button>

js code

 newRecord(){
    
        if(this.recordApiName == 'Account') {
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__objectPage',
                attributes: {
                    objectApiName: 'Account',
                    actionName: 'new'
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Could you give more context to what you try to achieve ? Don't be shy, it will help us to help you.
If my guess is correct, you have a "new account" button in a LWC component and you want when it is clicked to open the new account standard form. Salesforce by default opens the form in a new tab/subtab (you use the lightning console ui I guess). You want instead to open it inside a dialog box on top of your current page ?

Comment: Yes. I have a lightning button in a  lwc component , on click of the button I am calling the javascript function to invoke the this[NavigationMixin.Navigate] but the new object page is opening in a subtab instead of the pop window.                   
 <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Click to create record" onclick={newRecord} class="slds-m-around_large"></lightning-button> . Below is the javascript fs code newRecord(){ this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({ type: 'standard__objectPage', attributes: {   objectApiName: 'Account', actionName: 'new'  }

Comment: Ok, so first there is no standard way for this (like just passing a parameter). You can therefore do it using custom code. I'm going to write an answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your LWC component could have a [lightning-quick-action-panel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions_screen) that will embed a [lightning-record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation).
You can also get the fields from the [api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_create_record_values) so that you can still configure it through page layout.

For example:

**myComponent.html**

```html
<template>
    <lightning-button
        variant="brand"
        label="Click to create record"
        onclick={newRecord}
        class="slds-m-around_large"
    ></lightning-button>

    <lightning-record-edit-form
        if:true={showForm}
    >
        <lightning-quick-action-panel
            object-api-name="Account"
            onsuccess={closeDialog}
        >
            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>

            <lightning-input-field
                for:each={fields}
                for:item="field"
                field-name={field.fieldApiName}
            ></lightning-input-field>

            <lightning-button
                class="slds-m-top_small"
                type="submit"
                label="Create new"
            ></lightning-button>
        </lighting-record-edit-form>
    </lightning-quick-action-panel>
</template>
```

**myComponent.js**

```js
import ACCOUNT_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name'


export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    fields = [
        ACCOUNT_NAME.fieldApiName,
    ]

    showForm = false

    newRecord () {
        this.showForm = true
    }

    closeDialog () {
        this.showForm = false
    }
}
```

Note that this is just a simple example, you have to read the provided documentation and go through your trials & errors to get the perfect result. If you have specific questions along the way I and the community will be happy to answer them.